# Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC comes empty after post when need to go back to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-helper

Well as said the description, when I pass data from the get of my method to the view everything its fine, but, when i hit save button and it goes to the server to validate if model is valid, if certanly its valid everyting its ok, but, if the model is not valid he go back to the same view (as is suppouses to do), but it lost the collection when it goes to the server, I consider is so stupid fill it again, so, Theres any way to fill the model only one tyme for the select list?.

I have those actions

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var types = _context.Types;

    var vm = new EventViewModel
    {
        Types = new SelectList(types, "Id", "Name")
    };

    return View(vm);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(EventViewModel vm)
{
    //when it enter here **Types** comes empty  
    //if is not valid
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            //var types = _context.Types;
            //**I WANT TO AVOID THIS**
            //vm.Types = new SelectList(types, "Id", "Name", vm.TypeId);
            return View(vm);
    }

    var ev = new Event
    {
        DateTime = vm.GetDateTime(),
        TypeId = vm.TypeId,
        Venue = vm.Venue,
        CoachId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
    };

    _context.Add(ev);

    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

}
```

This is my view

```
@model EcCoach.Web.ViewModels.EventViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>
<form asp-action="Create">
    <p class="alert alert-info">
        All fields are <strong>required</strong>
    </p>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Venue"> </label>
        <input asp-for="Venue" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a 
        venue" autofocus="autofocus">
        <span asp-validation-for="Venue"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Date"> </label>
        <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" placeholder="eg 
        15/12/2017">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Time"> </label>
        <input asp-for="Time" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TypeId"> </label>
        <select asp-for="TypeId" asp-items="@Model.Types" class="form- 
            control">
            <option value="0">Choose One</option>
        </select>          
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Save
    </button>

</form>
```

And finally this is my ViewModel

```
    public class EventViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [FutureDate]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ValidTime]
        public string Time { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte TypeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string Venue { get; set; }

        public DateTime GetDateTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Parse($"{Date} {Time}");
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Types { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few ways to do it.
The worst way is to store this values on the UI in the hidden inputs in the form, so the will be added to the POST request and you will recive them as a part of the VM in your post method. It's bad because everyone can change them, and it can be source of vulnerability. You should never trust users input.
The second way is to store the original VM in the session. If you are not required to be statless - it's the best solution. So, in the GET action you should store the VM in the session before returning to the client. In the post request you will recive the requestVM as the method paramter ( from the post). It will contains only user input. Then, you should get the sessionVM from the session, map user input from requestVM to sessionVM. Finaly, in the sessionVM you will have all values that you had on GET + updated fields from user input. Then you should validate the sessionVM and use the values from it to update the DB. If the validation fails, you should return the view with the sessionVM as a model.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2#using-imemorycache) to save the list of type into cache.

1.In startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMemoryCache();
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

2.ApplicationDbContext:

```
public DbSet<Type> Types {get;set;}
```

3.Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    private IMemoryCache _cache;


    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _context = context;
        _cache = memoryCache;

    }


    public IActionResult Create()
    {           
        var types = _context.Types.AsNoTracking().ToList();

        var vm = new EventViewModel
        {
            Types = new SelectList(types, "Id", "Name")
        };

        _cache.Set("types",types);//cache data
        return View(vm);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(EventViewModel vm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

           var types = _cache.Get<List<Type>>("types");//get cached data

           vm.Types = new SelectList(types, "Id", "Name", vm.TypeId);
           return View(vm);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, I will be doing the same thing than I want to avoid, than its going again to the database, so, its not aplicable for me

Comment: @sgrysoft Hi,I know your consideration now.I changed my answer which uses a IMemoryCache to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

This case can also be seen in the documentation of Microsoft.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.0#update-the-instructor-create-page)

A part of the example:

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Instructor>(
  newInstructor,
  "Instructor",
  i => i.FirstMidName, i => i.LastName,
  i => i.HireDate, i => i.OfficeAssignment))
{
  _context.Instructors.Add(newInstructor);                
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
PopulateAssignedCourseData(_context, newInstructor);
return Page();
```

If the validation fails (or something else), the method `PopulateAssignedCourseData(_context, newInstructor);` that recreates the data is called again.